# Javascript Variables and If function based on HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am struggling to get this to work. I have a HTML from that was working fine and popping up with a prompt asking if I want to make the task public, but I then wanted to add another part in the make public part.

I wanted to then check a value on the form if it was made public:

```
echo "<label>Notify Creditor Of Update?</label>\n";
echo "<select name=\"send_options\" id=\"send_options\" class=\"\">\n";
echo "<option selected=\"\" value=\"n\">No</option>\n";
echo "<option value=\"y\" selected>Yes</option>\n";
echo "</select>\n";
```

So I thought that creating `var notify = jQuery('#send_options').val();` would select the value from the above code.

Then IF the option selected is NOT y then popup asking if I want to Notify the client, If I select OK then notify, if I click Cancel, then do nothing about notifying them.

```
if (confirm('Do you wish to make this task public?')) {
    // Make it public
    jQuery.get('CODE_PATH_TO_EXECUTE', function (data) {
        jQuery('#taskTopOut-<?php echo $rightId;?>').append(data);
    });

    var notify =  $('#send_options option:selected').val();
    alert(notify);
    if((notify != 'y'))
    {
        confirm('Do you wish to notify client?');
        {
        // Notify
        jQuery.get('CODE_PATH_TO_EXECUTE', function (data) {
            jQuery('#taskTopOut-<?php echo $rightId;?>').append(data);
        });

    }
} else {
    // Not notify
}
} else {
    // Not public
    jQuery.get('CODE_PATH_TO_EXECUTE', function (data) {

    });

}
```

Comment: and the question is ... ?

Comment: That code does not look like it would run at all at the moment: `confirm('Do you wish to notify client?')) {` appears to have an extra closing bracket?

Comment: Removed the additional ) issue now ive noticed is when I select something on the dropdown, the selected option still says ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use to get the selected value:

```
   var notify =  $('#send_options option:selected').val();
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FqZ5E/)

UPDATE:

I think the question is not clear that all, but after your comment you are looking for:

```
$('#send_options').on('change', function(){       
   var $value=this.value;
   $('#send_options option').removeAttr('selected'); //remove selected that all option
   $('#send_options option[value='+ $value+']').attr("selected", "selected") //add selected to option selected
})
```

[DEMO UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/FqZ5E/2/)

Comment: No, not in Firebug, however, even if I select "No" it only recognizes yes, I have edited my original post with the new inserted code so you can see where im at. I also added an alert to see which one has been selected

Comment: Ok, but whole the code is trigger from? onchange(), click()? Becouse if you see the fiddle the soluton works.

Comment: I am not sure that you completely understand what im am trying to achieve? What I want is when an option is selected, to make that the selected value. EG: IF Yes is selcted
<option value=\"n\">No</option>
<option value=\"y\" selected>Yes</option>
OR IF No is Selected:
<option value="n" selected>No</option>
<option value="y">Yes</option>